# c output to php and using ajax to continue reading php file for changes

Tags: ajax, jquery

Instead of getting the output of my c program to the console, I wrote it to a php file to be used in ajax call.

C

```
char data[] = "ONLINE";

FILE *samplephp = fopen("/var/www/web.php", "w");
fprintf(samplephp, "<?php echo '%s'; ?>",data);
fclose(samplephp);
```

Using ajax call

```
    $.ajax({ url: '/var/www/web.php',
         data: {action: 'test'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(data) {

                      if(data=="ONLINE"){

$('body').append('ONLINE');

}else{

$('body').append('OFFLINE');

//loop and wait for the data to become "ONLINE"

}
                  }
});
```

The ajax call should keep on reading web.php e.g looping until data changes from offline to online or vice versa offline to online. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this piece of JavaScript. In addition, I think you don't have to use a PHP script; a simple plain text file is enough for your requirement, which is much faster.

```
var fetchStatus = function() {
$.ajax({ url: '/var/www/web.php',
     data: {action: 'test'},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(data) {
         if(data=="ONLINE"){
             $('body').append('ONLINE');
         }else{
             $('body').append('OFFLINE');
         }
         setTimeout(fetchStatus, 5000); //Fetch status every 5 seconds
     }
});
};
fetchStatus();  // Start loop
```

For realtime applications, you should try something implemented "server-side push", like WebSocket. I'm using [Wrench WebSocket Server](https://github.com/varspool/Wrench) written in PHP; it's running as a independent process, so you should find some way, like [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) or socket for your C app to communicate with it. Here's a example of [browser-side WebSocket app](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html).

Comment: @Defyleiti No, you can try WebSocket if you really need it realtime, and use this as a fallback in older browser.

Comment: I see thank you for this answer. I'll look into websockets. Or can you point me to a websocket that I can use for this kind of situation?

Comment: Thank you and great explanation, this should get me going.

Comment: Can I combine node.js and wrench together. node.js will read the file and wrench will connect to node.js to get the data.

Comment: @Defyleiti Of course it's ok, and there is node.js websocket server as well.